# How to add something to the index, commit it, then push the master branch to a named remote with dulwich?

Tags: python, git, dulwich

How can I add something to the index, as in

```
git add .
```

then

```
git commit -m "message"
```

then

```
git push origin master
```

using dulwich?

So far I've found this http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/apidocs/dulwich.index.Index.html but it doesn't say much, does it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a tested answer but it is closer on the push part:

```
# set wants to master
def wantmaster(haves, wants):
  global repo
  return { "refs/heads/master": repo.refs["HEAD"] }

client, src = dulwich.client.get_transport_and_path(origin_uri) 

client.send_pack(src, wantmaster, repo.object_store.generate_pack_contents)
```

A variation on this is working in my code.

Comment: how to add all and commit them?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you don't want the index but the repo (of which the index is a part). http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/apidocs/dulwich.repo.Repo.html

Something like this should work:

```
>>> from dulwich.repo import Repo
>>> x = Repo('.')
>>> x.stage(['a'])
>>> x.do_commit(message="foo")
'151915d47467696d2f9d18de6f61be7168682aeb'
```

Comment: i tested your code,but commit seems empty...no file added